# Values being overwritten in array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm Java guy trying to solve discrete knapsack problem in c++. However, I'm having trouble with pointers. I have an object with a field

```
Item ** items;
```

representing array of items to choose from. I also created a method to add an item which works like insertion sort (at least I hope so).

```
void Knapsack::addItem(Item item) {

int k = itemCount - 1;

if (this->items[k] != NULL) {
    return;
}

while (k > 0 && this->items[k - 1] == NULL) {
    k--;
}

if (k == 0) {
    this->items[0] = &item;
} else {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < k && item < *(this->items[i])) {
        i++;
    }

    for (int n = k; n > i; n--) {
        this->items[n] = this->items[n - 1];
    }

    this->items[i] = &item;
}
}
```

Later, in my main I invoke the method by

```
knapsack->addItem(*(new Item(values.at(0), values.at(1))));
```

values being a vector of ints. The method itself seems to work fine, however, debugger shows that everytime I invoke the method with new Item, the previous values already put in my array are set to the same values as the new item.
(ex. if items[0] has value of 5, and I invoke the method with an item valued as 10, the items[0] instantly is set to 10).

Why are the values overwritten? I am creating a new object everytime I invoke the method.

**EDIT:**

Problem was fixed by replacing

```
this->items[0] = &item;
this->items[i] = &item;
```

with

```
this->items[0] = new Item(item.getWeight(), item.getValue());
this->items[i] = new Item(item.getWeight(), item.getValue());
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

The answer shows better (and probably correct) way to do this. Now the function takes a pointer instead of an object.

```
void Knapsack::addItem(Item * item);
this->item[i] = item;
knapsack->addItem(new Item(values.at(0), values.at(1)));
```

Comment: [please don't.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Yea, I'm going to change vector to dynamic array later ;) However I don't think the error lies here.

Comment: If this method is making these changes, then it must be doing so at some line within that method.  Have you used your debugger to follow the execution of this method, so you can see when this change happens?

Comment: Yes I did, the values change immediately when the method is invoked.

Comment: `&item` is the address of the parameter. The pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Just from looking at your code, it seems like the problem could come from this->items[0] = &item;  You're setting the first value (items[0]) to item.  When you run this method when the array is empty, it works fine, but afterwards, it replaces the original element with the value of item, right?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that passing variables by array element or by pointer is the same as passing a variable by reference.

Comment: So, before inserting to an array, I need to create new Item having the same values as the one being passed?

Comment: Need an answer to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to a temporary copy of an `Item` object in the array in your `addItem` function, once the function returns the temporary object will be destroyed and you will be left with an invalid pointer. Make sure to allocate an `Item` object on the heap and passing a pointer to your `addItem` function or just use a vector of type `std::vector<Item>` and save your objects in there.

Comment: "allocate an Item on the heap" I don't understand that, did you mean stack?

Comment: No, using `new` to keep the object alive through function calls, I meant heap : http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/

Comment: Oh, thanks. I already solved the problem by creating new object with the same values inside function (see edit in question). However, your answer seems to be a lot better.